# save and retrieve multiple of arraylists to a file

Tags: java

Hi i was wondering if this was possible. i have 5 multiple array lists. after i add information to each array lists is it possible to save this as a single file using filechooser. i have 5 arraylist which i have created as a object from a different class.

```
hotelArrayObjects.getDahabArray()
hotelArrayObjects.getRomeArray()
hotelArrayObjects.getParisArray()
hotelArrayObject.getBerlinArray()
hotelArrayObjects.getNiceArray()
```

wondering if there was any way to do this. I was thinking of using Filechooser to make it more user friendly and easier to retrieve.

Any tips on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Do you want to save them as `objects` or as `text`?

Comment: Hmm Which one would be more appropriate? I think text would be ok

Comment: If you want text, then you have you created meaningful `toString()` methods?

Comment: I noticed that you plan to retrieve them? For what purpose? What do you intend to do with the retrieved data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use java.io.ObjectOutputStream and its subclasses for writing objects to files. You can read them back with java.io.ObjectInputStream and its subclasses. There are readObject() and writeObject() methods in these classes that you can use. Note that if you want to write an object to a file, the defining class of that object should be serializable. In you case, objects that you store in the ArrayList should be serializable.

Java mechanisms for storing and retrieving objects does not need the file to be selected with a FileChooser. You can use java.io.File class for opening a stream to your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the information within an arraylist, you can do a few forloops then use a file writer

```
String s1;
for(int i=0; i<arraylist.length(); i++) {
   s1+=arraylist.get(i);
}
```

repeat repeat
then use something like this:

```
String finalString = s1+s2+s3+s4+s5;
FileWriter fwrite = new FileWriter("hotels.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fwrite);
out.write(finalString);
```

Then you can use the JFileChooser to save that file.